# How to solve $\displaystyle \int \frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}dx$?

Tags: integration

I don't know how to solve the following integral. I need some suggestions. Thank you!

$\displaystyle \int \frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}dx$

(I need to use some kind of a substitution of the form $"u=sth"$, but I don't know what (I tried using substitutions of the form: $u=e^{-2x}$, $u=e^{2x}$, $u=e^{4x}$, $u=e^{4x}-1$, but it didn't help))

Comment: Maybe it helps that the integrand is $\coth(2x)$. The integral of that you can look up in a table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\displaystyle \int \frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}dx=\int\frac{\cosh(2x)}{\sinh(2x)}dx= \frac12\log\left(|\sinh(2x)|\right)+C$$

Comment: The solution is (according to the book): $-x+ \frac{ln(e^{4x}-1)}{2}+C$. How can I get that?

Comment: I know that yours is correct as well, I just want to know how to get to the solution that's written in the book (that's actually bothering me) :S

Comment: @L_McClain Expand $\sinh$

Comment: Write $2\sinh(2x)=e^{-2x}(e^{4x}-1)$ and simplify.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
$$d({e^{2x}+e^{-2x}})=2({e^{2x}-e^{-2x}})dx,\\
d({e^{2x}-e^{-2x}})=2({e^{2x}+e^{-2x}})dx$$

Comment: Everyone should forget about this $\coth$ stuff... isn't the above obvious?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1.** $$\int g(f(x)) f'(x) dt = \int g(t)dt,$$ where $f$ is continuously differentiable and $g$ is continuous on the range of $f$.

**Hint 2.** $\sinh'(2t)=(e^{2x}+e^{-2x})'=2(e^{2x} - e^{-2x})=2\cosh(2x)$

**Hint 3.** Try $f(x)=\sinh(2x), \ g(t)=1/t.$

**Hint 4.** Don't forget to re-substitute.

Comment: $\int 2cosh(2x)/sinh(2x)dt=\int 1/t dt=>tcosh(2x)/sinh(2x)=(1/2)log(t)$  be careful with $t$.

Answer (score 1):

(1) the integrand is $\coth 2x$ so simply you solve it
(2) the top is the derivative of the bottom by 2